# hash only returning 8 or 9 characters

Tags: java, hash

The link provided doesn't answer the question.  In the MessageDiggest it says:

```
toString()
Returns a string representation of this message digest object.
```

I'm unclear why this would always be only 8 or 9 characters.

I have the following method creating a hashed password.  It only returns 8 or 9 characters and I'm wondering if there is a problem with it:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Password {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String[] saltPassword = createPassword("password");

      System.out.println("Salt = " + saltPassword[0]);
      System.out.println("Password = " + saltPassword[1]);
   }

   private static String[] createPassword(String password) {
       String [] saltPassword = new String[2];
      try{  
         SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
         byte[] salt = new byte[32];
         random.nextBytes(salt);

         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
         md.update(salt);
         md.update(password.getBytes("UTF8"));
         byte[] digest = md.digest();

         saltPassword[0] = salt.toString();
         saltPassword[1] = digest.toString();    

         System.out.println(digest);


        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e1){
            System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: " + e1);
            System.exit(0);
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e2){
            System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: " + e2);
            System.exit(0);
        }

      return(saltPassword);
   }

}
```

Comment: BackSlash, I don't see how that reference answers my question.  Can you provide more guidance?  see updated question

Comment: `saltPassword[0] = salt.toString(); saltPassword[1] = digest.toString(); System.out.println(digest);` These lines don't do what you think. The duplicate question tells you why and how to print those arrays/convert them to string correctly.

Comment: compare the answer below which is very helpful to your link which is NOT helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this. Your code has no problem you are printing object reference. SHA-256 generate 64 length hex data equal to 32 byte. You can convert this byte data to another format using **DatatypeConverter** Class but below code may be serve your problem.

```
 private static String[] createPassword(String password) {
    String [] saltPassword = new String[2];
    try{
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(salt);
        md.update(password.getBytes("UTF8"));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        saltPassword[0] = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(salt);
        saltPassword[1] = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest);

        System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest));


    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e1){
        System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: " + e1);
        System.exit(0);
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e2){
        System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: " + e2);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return(saltPassword);
}
```

Comment: DatatypeConverter is no longer supplied with the JDK in Java 11. You can use it if you're still using Java 8.

Comment: Don't worry, the vast majority of Java developers are currently still using Java 8. I wrote the comment for the sake of developers in 3-4 years' time.